# if else if doesn't continue till the end

Tags: c#, if-statement

i'm working on win form application deals with XML files

i added this code to the form load event

```
if (!File.Exists("clients.xml"))
            {
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                lines.Add("<clients>");
                lines.Add("</clients>");
                File.WriteAllLines("clients.xml", lines);
            }
            else if (!File.Exists("cases.xml"))
            {
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                lines.Add("<names>");
                lines.Add("</names>");
                File.WriteAllLines("cases.xml", lines);
            }
            else if (!File.Exists("files.xml"))
            {
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                lines.Add("<num>");
                lines.Add("</num>");
                File.WriteAllLines("files.xml", lines);
            }
```

when i start my application if none of these three files exists
it only creates the first file!!

if the first file only exists it creates only the second file !!

if both exists then it creates the third one..

any idea what is wrong with this code?!!

thanks ...

Comment: That's pretty much what "else if" means... Get rid of the "else" and you're good to go.

Comment: Doctor Vista, very simple, remove else if, use just if

Comment: you haven't explained exactly what the expected behaviour is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution :** use `if` instead of `else-if` .

**Reason :** if you use combination of `if-else` it only executes `first true` scenario and skips the further.
but if you use `if` for all conditions it will execute `all true` scenarios.

**Code:**

```
                if (!File.Exists("clients.xml"))
                {
                    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                    lines.Add("<clients>");
                    lines.Add("</clients>");
                    File.WriteAllLines("clients.xml", lines);
                }
                 if (!File.Exists("cases.xml"))
                {
                    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                    lines.Add("<names>");
                    lines.Add("</names>");
                    File.WriteAllLines("cases.xml", lines);
                }
                if (!File.Exists("files.xml"))
                {
                    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                    lines.Add("<num>");
                    lines.Add("</num>");
                    File.WriteAllLines("files.xml", lines);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: if the first file not exists , that means this is a first start up for the application.. cuz every file depends on the previous one ..

Comment: using if only instead of else if got it Fixed Thanks a lot for helping ... but i don't know i thought else if is executed what ever the previous statement was ..

Comment: else-if is only for executing one of the true condition among multiple conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `else` from the `else if`.

This means that all of the `if` statements will be evaluated.

The way that you have it set up, it has a waterfall effect. If the first statement is false, evaluate the second. If that is false evaluate the third etc.

Comment: i was trying without it at first.. then i thought it might be need , both cases same result , with or without else !!

Answer (score 2):

**Do not do by the way you are doing:**

Rule of thumb: `Do not repeat the code`

Write a generic function like this:

```
public void DoStuff(string fileName, List<string> linesToBeWritten)
{
   var output = new List<string>();

   if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    return;

   output.Add("<" + fileName + ">");
   output.AddRange(linesToBeWritten); 
   output.Add("</" + fileName + ">");

   File.WriteAllLines(fileName, output);
}
```